# Is GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() use any proxy to download from .cache.js?

Tags: gwt

I'm not understanding working of code splitting. i read it in https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting but it doesn't specify about any proxy call to download code from .cache.js file. i want a clear idea about that means how it working. can anyone help me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `proxy call`?

Comment: means for calling a server program it uses proxy object.

Comment: /**
  * Create a remote service proxy to talk to the server-side Greeting service.
  */
 private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT
   .create(GreetingService.class);
I want to know how it is calling split points? the above code shows proxy object for calling server pgm...

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to GWT RPC in your comments.

1) **RPC** is for fetching your data from server side.

2) **Code Splitting** is for splitting up your GWT generated application javascript into smaller files and loading them as required when you navigate to the given screen or code execution.